# Attribute Address getting displayed instead of Attribute Value

Tags: python, html, django

I am try to create the following. I want to have one drop down menu. Depending on the option selected in the first drop down menu, options in second drop down menu will be displayed. The options in 2nd drop down menu is supposed by dynamic, i.e., options change with the change of values in first menu.

Here, instead of getting the drop down menus, I am getting the following

```
Choose your Option1: <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x02FE2C10> 
Choose your Option2: <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x02FE5A90>
```

Note: I strictly don't want to use javascript.

```
home_form.py

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        var_filter_con = kwargs.pop('filter_con', None)
        super(HomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if var_filter_con == '***':
            var_empty_label = None
        else:
            var_empty_label = '    '

        self.option2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = db_option2.objects.filter(option1_id = var_filter_con).order_by("name"),
                                        empty_label = var_empty_label,
                                        widget = forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'this.form.submit();'})
                                        )

        self.option1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = db_option1.objects.all().order_by("name"),
                                        empty_label=None,
                                        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'this.form.submit();'})
                                        )

view.py                                     

def option_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if cd.has_key('option1'):
                f = HomeForm(filter_con = cd.get('option1'))
                return render_to_response('homepage.html', {'home_form':f,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return render_to_response('invalid_data.html', {'form':form,},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        f = HomeForm(filter_con = '***')
        return render_to_response('homepage.html', {'home_form':f,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


homepage.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Nivaaran</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name = 'choose_opt' action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
        Choose your Option1:
            {{ home_form.option1 }}
        <br/>
        Choose your Option2:
            {{ home_form.option2 }}
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set option1 and option2 like this:

```
self.fields['option2']=forms.ModelChoiceField(...
self.fields['option1']=forms.ModelChoiceField(...
```

Comment: Hi, it worked. Can you let me know the difference and mistake that I was making.

Comment: Basically, in the `forms.Form` `__init__` method, it reads the class attributes (how you normally define your fields) and does some set up for later. When you refer to the `form.option1` it actually doesn't return `HomeForm.option1` (class attribute) but `form.fields['option1']` and so this is how you must add fields after the form is set up. Some more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `form` in this way, I can suggest another way of doing this:

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
     option1 =  forms.ChoiceField(attrs={"onChange":'this.form.submit();'})
     option2 =  forms.ChoiceField(attrs={"onChange":'this.form.submit();'})
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        var_filter_con = kwargs.pop('filter_con', None)
        super(HomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if var_filter_con == '***':
            var_empty_label = None
        else:
            var_empty_label = '    '

        self.fields['option1'].choices =  db_option1.objects.filter(option1_id = var_filter_con).order_by("name")

        self.fields['option2'].choices =  db_option2.objects.filter(option1_id = var_filter_con).order_by("name")
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Any reasons to your suggestion??

Comment: I think, my way of implementing is perhaps neat and its not like the solution is bad or anything, its pretty good actually(modelform is one of the best feature of django), but I can customize more in my way of implementation I think. :)

Comment: You know that those initialization which you added in the class is of class variables while I am using object variables. If you have some reason for it, please let me know.
FYI, I don't my program to be a beauty without brain.